# CKEditor5: HTML output formatting

Tags: ckeditor5

CKEditor5 saves the HTML as a single line. How can I achieve multi-line pretty-print HTML output? I can't find it for v5 (only for v4: Writer rules e.g. breakAfterClose: true).

I use `DecoupledEditor`. I use an submit click listener which posts the `editor.getData()` to the server.